# How to Blur DrawLine using Graphics?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, brush

I researched for weeks and did not find anything related, I wanted to know how to blur the graphics created in VB.NET, to do a Soft Brush like  Photoshop brush hardness.

**Example**

[image]

**My Code**

```
Dim DrawColor As Color = Color.Orange
Dim brushSize As Integer = 10

Public Pt As Point
Dim brush As New Pen(DrawColor, brushSize)

Private Sub PaintBrush(x As Integer, y As Integer)

    graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias
   'graphic.BLUR?
    graphic.DrawLine(brush, Pt, New Point(x, y))
    Pt = New Point(x, y)
    brush.Dispose()

  End Using
```

Comment: Just an idea / approach, you could use alpha transparency in the color, ie `color.fromargb(150,Color.Orange)` this with give an opactity to the stroke. Admititadly this is not a blurness, but could get you going on creating it.

Comment: _Gaussian Blur_ is one of the most common types of blur. It should produce a result close to your example.

Comment: Check [this](https://mobile.codeguru.com/columns/vb/creating-a-gaussian-blur-with-vb.net.htm) out!

Comment: Note that the Pen object is much more complex than that. It acceps a `Brush`; that brush can be a `LinearGradient` brush. You can apply a `Blend` and a `ColorBlend` pattern to the brush, a `LineCap` style, use `SetSigmaBellShape` to govern the color fall-offs. Apply transparency to the blending and the brush.

Comment: @preciousbetine  I hope nobody will ever use that code. First of all, is for Bitmaps only. Then, even though is dated 2014, it's actually taken from this CodeProject: [Gausian and Alpha Blurring](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6162/Gausian-and-Alpha-Blurring) (2004) and it's terrible in every aspect. Besides using `SetPixels` to blurr the image, it doesn't manage **any** of the objects it creates, resulting in a mess.

Comment: Blurring this in real time is the real challenge, because the two methods mentioned are unfeasible for a painting dynamics. Is there no possibility of doing something with at least PNG images already blurred in Photoshop for example ?!